# A 'Hartman-Grobman' for higher order approximations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The Hartman-Grobman theorem states that exists an homeomorphism carrying the solutions of linearized system near its equilibrium into the solutions of the non-linear system near its equilibrium, i.e., the linear system can be seen as a good approximation to the original one, near the equilibrium.

Is there a theorem that assures us that for a 2nd order Taylor approximation of the original system is a good approximation, when the linear system doesn't behave as the original one?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a short remark: where linearization and hyperbolicity fails, [center manifolds](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Center_manifold) and [normal forms](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Normal_forms) shine. What you want looks a bit like a truncation of normal form. As far as I know, you still can encounter problems when using normal forms, like the truncated dynamics doesn't behave exactly as non-truncated. And also you have to prove separately for each case of degeneracy that truncation works.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks for the remark ;)